# How to run ngCoradova github App?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I was just exploring the ng-coradova for ionic and came accross [this](https://github.com/driftyco/ng-cordova), I'm not getting how to run this App in mobile to test the device Api's

Here is what i did.

1. Cloned and moved to WIP-coradovaReady-new branch
2. Went into the demo folder
3. did `ionic platform add android`
4. then `ionic build android`

The Apk was generated but no functionalities worked when I installed it in phone.

Can anyone pls help or guide If I'm missing anything

chrome remote debugging shows empty screen

[image: empty image]

Comment: What did remote debug show you?

Comment: After i installed the Apk I could see the UI in a very good shape but functionalities doesn't work

Comment: So what did remote debug show you?

Comment: Im not getting sir what do you mean by remote debug doea it refer to some sort of log?

Comment: See https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging

Comment: Thank you sir for the tool I tried as per https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging#open-webview but i got an empty view on browser but on phone I'm getting the screen

Comment: Wow, I've never seen that before. I'm sorry - but I'm not sure what to suggest now.